# Singleton constructor fails c++ - what can be?

Tags: c++, exception, mfc, singleton, mutex

I am actually facing a huge problem: I have a singleton class. My program is a multi-threaded MFC, so the singleton's constructor can be called from different threads. I surrounded the singleton instance-getter function with a mutex to avoid deadlocks and multiple constructions. The call of the below meant function fails directly at the first time.

The function looks like (LOG_MSG macro logs the given string into my log file):

```
MyClass& MyClass::singleton ()
{
    LOG_MSG("MyClass::singleton -> jump in");

    static CMutex oInitMutex;
    try
    {
        CSingleLock oSingleLock((CSyncObject *) &oInitMutex, TRUE);
        LOG_MSG("!!! SINGLETON LOCK OKAY !!!");
        static MyClass oMyClassInstance;
        LOG_MSG("!!! SINGLETON CONSTRUCTION OKAY !!!");
        return oMyClassInstance;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        CString excMsg("Unexpected exception by creating MyClass singleton instance!");
        LOG_MSG(excMsg);
        throw excMsg;
    }
}
```

I've figured out, that the construction of the singleton object will NOT fail (since we get the "!!! SINGLETON CONSTRUCTION OKAY !!!" message).

Log output says:

```
09.04.2013 ;07:14:51:832;"MyClass::singleton -> jump in"
09.04.2013 ;07:14:51:841;"!!! SINGLETON LOCK OKAY !!!"
... (constructor logs => NOTHING unexpected in it!!! everything runs fine, as they must!!!)
09.04.2013 ;07:14:52:125;"!!! SINGLETON CONSTRUCTION OKAY !!!"
09.04.2013 ;07:14:52:170;"Unexpected exception by creating MyClass singleton instance!"
```

What does it means? When would a *return* statement throw exception(s)??? Please help me resolve this matter...

Comment: It doesn't have to be the `return` statement that causes the exception, but the destruction of the `oSingleLock` object? You have to run your program in a debugger to get more information.

Comment: Is mutex required for static object? It is not a pointer, complete object is static

Comment: So why is your mutex outside the try block? Got nefarious plans for that thing?

Comment: "I am actually facing a huge problem: I have a singleton class." Yup, that pretty much summarizes it. Very often, singletons are more trouble than they are worth.

Comment: Angew, you are maybe right, but now I can't change the entire program to cut singleton off from it. :(

Comment: Abhijit Kadam: if the mutex is not present, then the singleton's constructor keeps on creating his instance continuosly until stack overflow will be occurred...

Comment: @A.V. in a word, "huh?" Any chance you can post MyClass? at least the header decl? This is a static, so unless you have a reference to `singleton()` in the constructor of MyClass (and you would be insane to do so), what you just described isn't possible.

Comment: What do you think is going to protect simultaneous construction and access of oInitMutex. Easiest way out would be to use double check lock pattern on a pointer to MyClass object that would reside in Heap.

Comment: "When would a return statement throw exception(s)???" When the destructor of an automatic object throws one. Possibly, the destructor of `CSingleLock`. You might try catching `std::exception const & ex`, and printing `ex.what()` to see if you get more details.

Comment: The static mutex's own data will be overwritten by a misplaced indexing in the class constructor. That was the main cause of this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

> I figured out the problem, it was not easy. To learn from my error, I
>   will share the code, caused the failure.
>
> In the constructor I use an `sscanf` function call in improper way:
>
> ```
> const char* sBuffer;
> // some stuff here that fills the sBuffer up
> sscanf(sBuffer, "%X %X %X %X", &tags_[0], &tags_[1], &tags_[2], &tags_[3]);
> ```
>
> The array was defined in the singleton class as:
>
> ```
> private:
>     char tags_[4];
> ```
>
> Beware: the format codes awating specific type of variables to be able
>   to write the data in. For example: in my case the `tags_` array should
>   be an array of integers instead of array of chars. Since the singleton class 
>   should store the `tags_`, after indexing the 2nd, 3rd and 4th element,
>   the `sscanf` function will write into an undefined place of memory,
>   something will be overwritten about the static class's data, which
>   caused multiple instancing of it, however: this can be avoided by
>   mutexing, but in that case the mutex object will be overwritten.
>   More infos about required types for (s)scanf can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/).

**CONCLUSION:**

> Be smart and aware of using C-functions/low-level calls. Pay a lot of
>   attention on input parameters, not only their value, but their type
>   too. If you support other type as expected, the behaviour of your program will be
>   undefined, but you won't get compiler error: it is very hard to find out
>   that issue later on.

Answer (score 5):

While this doesn't answer your particular question, it's still a solution to your overall problem: you don't need the mutex *at all.* The C++11 standard [stmt.dcl]§4 specifies (when talking about `static` variables local to functions):

> If control enters the declaration concurrently while the variable is
>   being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion
>   of the initialization.<sup>88</sup> If control re-enters the declaration
>   recursively while the variable is being initialized, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Where note 88 is:

> Note 88: The implementation must not introduce any deadlock around
>   execution of the initializer.

In other words, the compiler introduces synchronisation for you; no need to do that manually.

Comment: I am working with Visual Studio 6.0, that is in that case a must: so, the new C++11 standard won't have to do anything with my code... :(

Comment: @A.V.: In that case, (a) you're going to have a lot of problems; and (b) you'd better mention that you're using a prehistoric compiler when you need help, since the language you're using bears little resemblance to modern C++.

Comment: @A.V. In that case, I have just one advice for you: upgrade your compiler, or if that's in a job and you're not allowed to upgrade, just quit. If an employer is forcing their employees to work with broken tools, they don't deserve employees. Would you work in construction if you were only allowed wooden hammers, not steel ones?

Comment: @A.V. Also, even though C++03 never mentions concurrency explictly, the same semantics can be implied from its wording: "such an object is initialized the first time control passes through its declaration ... If control re-enters the declaration (recursively) while the object is being initialized, the behavior is undefined." Not that VC 6 ever cared much about standards, but it might still apply. Are you even sure the mutex is necessary (if you temporarily make the `MyClass` constructor trivial, does it still fail without it)?

Comment: Angew: that's true. I don't know the main cause of the constrution failure, but already true that it is caused by an internal "shit", independent from mutexes. So, I have to double check the code and look for the main source of problem.

Comment: In debug mode, the mutexing won't fail, but in release the 'Unlock' function of the mutex object fails, that's why we get the exception. It's strange, isn't it? :)